# Android app does not get into onTouch method

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, ontouch

I'm having troubles with the method onTouch(). The code I'm using to implement it is the following.

```
public class EjemploView extends View implements OnTouchListener  {
...
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getActionMasked()==0) {
                slider2.setCenX(slider2.getCenX() - 1);
            }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The point is that I set a debugger stop inside onTouch method and even if I touch the screen it will never go inside it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I'm adding some drawables to the view and they display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer, simply so that it makes more sense.
You are implementing onTouchListener but you dont set it as your onTouchListener. Thus you are left with a fully functioning onTouchListener in your view that does not ever get called.

```
public EjemploView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        /** \/ Add this line right here \/ */
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        drawableFader = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.fader);
        drawableSlider=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.slider);

        fader1 = new Grafico(this, drawableFader);
        fader2 = new Grafico(this, drawableFader);
        slider1 = new Grafico(this, drawableSlider);
        slider2 = new Grafico(this, drawableSlider);


        fader1.setAlto(350);
        fader1.setAncho(64);
        fader2.setAlto(350);
        fader2.setAncho(64);
        fader2.setAngulo(90);


        slider1.setAlto(90);
        slider1.setAncho(55);
        slider2.setAlto(90);
        slider2.setAncho(55);
        slider2.setAngulo(90);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(new EjemploView(this));
```

That's the place where I instantiate the view

```
public class EjemploView extends View implements OnTouchListener  {

    private Drawable drawableFader, drawableSlider;
    private Grafico fader1, fader2, slider1, slider2;

    public EjemploView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        drawableFader = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.fader);
        drawableSlider=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.slider);

        fader1 = new Grafico(this, drawableFader);
        fader2 = new Grafico(this, drawableFader);
        slider1 = new Grafico(this, drawableSlider);
        slider2 = new Grafico(this, drawableSlider);


        fader1.setAlto(350);
        fader1.setAncho(64);
        fader2.setAlto(350);
        fader2.setAncho(64);
        fader2.setAngulo(90);


        slider1.setAlto(90);
        slider1.setAncho(55);
        slider2.setAlto(90);
        slider2.setAncho(55);
        slider2.setAngulo(90);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int ancho, int alto, int ancho_anter, int alto_anter) {
        super.onSizeChanged(ancho, alto, ancho_anter, alto_anter);
        // Una vez que conocemos nuestro ancho y alto.

        fader1.setCenX(ancho / 4 - 31);
        fader1.setCenY(alto / 4 - 50);
        slider1.setCenX(ancho / 4 - 28);
        slider1.setCenY(alto / 4 - 50);
        fader2.setCenX(ancho - 271);
        fader2.setCenY(alto / 4 - 50);
        slider2.setCenX(ancho - 277);
        slider2.setCenY(alto / 4 - 50);
    }

    @Override
    synchronized protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        fader1.dibujaGrafico(canvas);
        fader2.dibujaGrafico(canvas);
        slider1.dibujaGrafico(canvas);
        slider2.dibujaGrafico(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("TAG", "I've reached this point");
            if(event.getActionMasked()==0) {
                slider2.setCenX(slider2.getCenX() - 2);
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And that's my whole code for the view. It is displaying it because I can see the drawables.

Comment: in your constructor, after you call super, i believe you need to add this line of code

setOnTouchListener(this);

The reason being, is that you implement an onTouchListener and you give it code, but you never tell the view that you want it to be its own onTouchListener.

Comment: Absolutely. I added that as an answer. If you could accept either mine or Hegazy's answer that would be awesome and also prevent additional answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing a new interface, but you should use the already defined `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`. Just override it.

```
class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(action));

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare it as the correct answer if it solves the problem